# Add to PATH from Laravel Sail Dockerfile

Tags: laravel, docker, dockerfile, laravel-sail

I'm trying to add sqlpackage to a Laravel Sail Docker. While this is normally not really difficult, Sail makes it kinda hard.

I have the following section in my Dockerfile

```
RUN curl -L https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2157202 -o /usr/local/bin/sqlpackage.zip
RUN mkdir /usr/local/bin/sqlpackage
RUN unzip /usr/local/bin/sqlpackage.zip -d /usr/local/bin/sqlpackage
RUN rm /usr/local/bin/sqlpackage.zip
RUN echo "export PATH=\"\$PATH:$HOME/usr/local/bin/sqlpackage\"" >> /home/sail/.bashrc
RUN chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/sqlpackage/sqlpackage
```

First off, I'm not happy with the install path I've chosen (`/usr/local/bin`). But it's the best I could think of. Any suggestions are welcome.

My second, and more important issue is that I can't add run the echo to the path when installing. The install script can't reach the home path. Would really like a solution for this. But I get this error:

`cannot create /home/sail/.bashrc: Directory nonexistent`

However it exists. So it's a rights issue for the installing user. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: are you sure /home/sail exists ? if not create such user `RUN useradd sail` before export

Comment: You can add `run mkdir -p /home/sail/` before `run echo ...` to make it existed. Also I recommend you change the `run echo ...` command to `RUN echo "export PATH='$PATH:$HOME/usr/local/bin/sqlpackage'" >> /home/sail/.bashrc`, but in this case `$HOME` means `/root/` am I right?

Comment: `$HOME`  is not required in echo export

Comment: Ah snap, missed that. User sail gets created later. Your comments made me realize that.

Comment: @Matt i just added answer, hope this helps good day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> cannot create /home/sail/.bashrc: Directory nonexistent

It looks like user sail doesn't exist so

before

```
RUN echo "export PATH=\"\$PATH:$HOME/usr/local/bin/sqlpackage\"" >> /home/sail/.bashrc
```

Create user like below

```
# add user
RUN useradd sail

# and then
RUN echo "export PATH=\"\$PATH:/usr/local/bin/sqlpackage\"" >> /home/sail/.bashrc
```

Also `$HOME` is not required, because during build time it become
`export PATH="$PATH:/root/usr/local/bin/sqlpackage"`

Try below on terminal ( for example I am as root user ):

```
$ echo "export PATH=\"\$PATH:$HOME/usr/local/bin/sqlpackage\"" 
export PATH="$PATH:/root/usr/local/bin/sqlpackage"
```

Similar way during build process it will use current user that is root.

> First off, I'm not happy with the install path I've chosen
> (/usr/local/bin). But it's the best I could think of. Any suggestions
> are welcome.

`/usr/local/bin` is the location for all add-on executables that you add to the system to be used as common system files by all users. Locally installed software must be placed within `/usr/local`.

```
# Used for non-system libraries and executables
/usr/local/bin
```

`usr` stands for User System Resources. This is the location that system programs and libraries are stored.

`local` represents resources that were not shipped with the standard distribution and, usually, compiled and maintained on a per site basis.

`bin` represents binary compiled executables.

**So keep in mind these three**

- `/usr/bin`: User commands.
- `/usr/sbin`: System administration commands.
- `/usr/local/bin`: Locally customized software.

`/opt` is a directory for installing unbundled packages that is packages not part of the Operating System distribution, but provided by an independent source. I usually put all 3rd party packages in `/opt`